# Why is declared variable being changed automatically from String to Variant type?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a case in VBA for Excel where all but the last of list of variables declared on a single line like this...

```
Dim str1, str2, str3(), str4() As String
```

... are being automatically changed from String type to Variant type. But when I declare them on separate lines like this...

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim str3() As String
Dim str4() As String
```

... then they stay as String type. Why on earth is this happening?

I have a little VBA sub to read through input from a named range ("UserInput") in the worksheet and when a particular string is reached, to then take some adjacent data and read into an array. It works fine when I declare the variables on separate lines, but not when I combine them (because the Split function must pass to a String array). Can anybody explain why the variable type for str3 and str4 is being automatically changed from String to Variant?

```
Dim var1(), var2() As Variant
Dim str1, str2, str3(), str4() As String
Dim Reach_step, Reach_upper(), ReachM() As Double
Dim iRowNum, j, k As Long

var1 = Range("UserInput")
str1 = "Reach_main"

iRowNum = 1

Do While var1(iRowNum, 1) <> str1
    iRowNum = iRowNum + 1
Loop

str3 = Split(CStr(var1(iRowNum + 1, 2)), ",")
Reach_step = WorksheetFunction.Convert(CDbl(var1(iRowNum + 2, 2)), var1(iRowNum + 2, 3), "ft")
str4 = Split(CStr(var1(iRowNum + 3, 2)), ",")
```

In this case "UserInput" is a range that includes some names (and blanks) in the left column and some comma delimited numbers (and blanks) in the middle column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in VBA

```
Dim a, b, c As String
```

declares `c As String` but `a` and `b` remain `Variant`. Excel always assumes `Variant` if no type is specified.
It is the same as writing:

```
Dim a
Dim b
Dim c As String
```

So if you want all 3 to be strings you need to specify a type for every variable:

```
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
```

> **Note:**
>   This is different from VB.NET where `Dim a, b, c As String` declares all 3 as strings.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the explanation! I thought I had seen somewhere that in VBA you could put them on one line, but obviously I missed the mark.

Answer (score 3):

That is how vba works:

with:

> `Dim str1, str2, str3(), str4() As String`

only `str4()` is being declared as a string, the other three are variant.

You need to spell out each one individually:

```
 Dim str1 As String str2 As String, str3() As String, str4() As String
```

So

```
Dim var1(), var2()
Dim str1 As String str2 As String, str3() As String, str4() As String
Dim Reach_step As Double, Reach_upper() As Double, ReachM() As Double
Dim iRowNum As Long, j As Long, k As Long
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want it all on one line, then you have to do it like this:

```
Dim str1 As String, str2 As String, str3() As String, str4() As String
```

If you don't specify, they are `Variant` type.